# How to change address of a static array variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Let's assume we have defined a variable like this :

```
static struct array myVar;
// &myVar is 0x100
```

Is it possible to change it's address without touching it's declaration ?
Too be more clear I don't want to declare it as pointer.

```
// &myVar should be != 0x100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comment you said :

> Well, I'm asking this because while I was debugging a C++ program I saw visual studio to show different addresses at runtime with &myVar

If you have declared `myVar` in *.h* file which you have included in multiple *.cpp* file, then in each *.cpp* file you will see different address of `myVar`. It is because `myVar` has **internal linkage** as it is declared `static`. Internal linkage means each translation unit (*.cpp* file) will have different definition of the variable. So if there are N *.cpp* files, there are basically N version of `myVar` each with different address. That is one possible explanation!

The fix is this:

- Declare the variable as `extern` instead of `static` in the `.h` file:

  ```
   //file.h
   extern struct array myVar; //it is just a declaration
  ```
- Then in exactly one `.cpp` file, define it, without `static` keyword:

  ```
   //anyfile.cpp
   struct array myVar; //it is a definition!
  ```

Comment: THATS IT !. Is there a way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to change the address of `myVar` at runtime.

> I'm asking this because while I was debugging a C++ program I saw visual studio to show different addresses at runtime with `&myVar`

`myVar` could well be assigned different addresses during different runs of your program.

If the address is changing *during the same run*, the two most likely explanations are:

- you have more than one `myVar`;
- the debugger is not displaying the address correctly.

Comment: Well, I'm asking this because while I was debugging a C++ program I saw visual studio to show different addresses at runtime with &myVar...

Comment: @Mahdi: If it's the same `myVar`, its address won't change while the program is running.

Comment: @Mahdi Visual Studio uses `ASLR` - address space layout randomization, the runtime assigns a new address every time you start the program.

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Nobody has noticed the `static` keyword in the question. Please see my answer and upvote me :D

Comment: @Nawaz: That was well-spotted!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your program, the compiler replaces the symbol `myVar` with an address in memory. All addresses are assigned either at compile time, like with your `struct` or at runtime, when using dynamic memory with the `new`-operator. So it is not possible to change the address of the variable, it would be catastrophic if you could do.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the compiler/linker environment that you are using. This would be entirely outside the C or C++ standards, but some (if not most) compilers allow you to assign the "section" (or something similar) that the data or code ends up in, and then you can tell the linker what address.

But that's probably not what is happening in a visual studio compile without a lot of effort.